# Split string in fixed length number

Tags: ruby, string

I have a problem using `scan` with strings. My string is: (text variable)

```
"Nao ha nada novo porque somos preguicosos."
```

I use:

```
textdata = text.scan(/.{#{text.length - clearnum }}/)
```

`textdata[0]` is:

```
"Nao ha nada novo porque somos preguicoso"
```

and `textdata[1]` is nothing. I need `textdata[1]` to be `"s."`. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Have no idea what you are asking

Comment: you just want the last 2 characters of any string?

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to clarify. If `text = "Nap..."`, you should write it that way. If `clearnum` equals `2`, write `clearnum = 2`. I suggest you say what you want the array `textdata` to contain and merely ask  how you can do that. Yes, regular expressions can be used, but there are other ways that use only methods of the `String` class. You'll learn how to do it both ways if you focus on your end objective rather than limiting answers to the use of regexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this

```
clearnum = 2
text0 = text[0, text.length -clearnum]
text1 = text[-clearnum,clearnum]
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want:

```
text = "Nao ha nada novo porque somos preguicosos."
clearnum = 2
textdata = text.scan(/.{1,#{text.length - clearnum }}/)
#=> ["Nao ha nada novo porque somos preguicoso", "s."]
```

Comment: Yeah, but I receive three values: textdata[0] = ""Nao ha nada novo porque somos preguicos" textdata[1] = s and textdata[2] = .

Comment: Then you're doing something weird or using a strange ruby.